# SCALA and Elastic Search: Add symbol to classpath (Databricks)

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, dependencies, sbt, databricks

:)

I'm getting an error that I have no idea how to fix.. I could not really find outstanding documentation for this SchemaRDD type, and how to use it.

**build.sbt contains:**

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.4.1"
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.3.5"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-core" % "1.11.534"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-encryption-sdk-java" % "1.3.6"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.550"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" %% "elasticsearch-spark-1.2" % "2.4.4"
```

**Error:**

```
Symbol 'type org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD' is missing from the classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by 'value org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.package.rdd'.
[error] Make sure that type SchemaRDD is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'package.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.sql.
```

Thank you a lot for all kind of support! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency `elasticsearch-spark-1.2` is for Spark 1.x, need to use `elasticsearch-spark-20` instead. [The latest version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11/7.1.1) is built for Spark 2.3

```
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" %% "elasticsearch-spark-20" % "7.1.1"
```

Comment: Thank you, in the end it turned out that I was using a wrong library, I had to use the elasticsearch-hadoop. But thank you a lot for your response!!